# Visual Studio Team Services Build Nuget Publish step succeeds but does not update packages in internal feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

I have recently been having an issue with my Visual Studio Team Services build where the build will succeed (including the publish step) but the packages do not update in my internal feed.

The internal feed url is set to the package source URL given by clicking the "connect to feed" button on the package tab. I have no other advanced options selected.

Log indicates that the package was successfully pushed, but the packages available both on the packages tab page on VS Team Services and nuget package manager in visual studio do not update.

```
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4283862Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe arg: push
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4283862Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe arg: -NonInteractive
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4283862Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe pathArg: C:\a\1\s\xxxxx.1.0.0-ci-20160825-110532.nupkg
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4283862Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe arg: C:\a\1\s\xxxxx.1.0.0-ci-20160825-110532.nupkg
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4293861Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe arg: ["-Source","https://xyz.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json"]
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4303857Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe arg: ["-ApiKey","VSTS"]
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4303857Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe arg: -ConfigFile
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4303857Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe pathArg: C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_209.config
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4313859Z ##[debug]C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe arg: C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_209.config
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4313859Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4313859Z ##[debug]Arguments:
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4323857Z ##[debug]   push
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4323857Z ##[debug]   -NonInteractive
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4323857Z ##[debug]   C:\a\1\s\xxxxx1.0.0-ci-20160825-110532.nupkg
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4323857Z ##[debug]   -Source
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4333856Z ##[debug]   https://xyz.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4333856Z ##[debug]   -ApiKey
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4333856Z ##[debug]   VSTS
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4343860Z ##[debug]   -ConfigFile
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4343860Z ##[debug]   C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_209.config
2016-08-25T11:05:52.4343860Z[command] C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe push -NonInteractive C:\a\1\s\xxxxx.1.0.0-ci-20160825-110532.nupkg -Source https://xyz.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json -ApiKey VSTS -ConfigFile C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_209.config
2016-08-25T11:05:53.2954820Z Using credentials from config.UserName: VssSessionToken
2016-08-25T11:05:53.5047618Z Pushing xxxxx 1.0.0-ci-20160825-110532 to 'https://xyz.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/a79b39b4-256d-4964-911f-6918157c1720/nuget/v2/'...
2016-08-25T11:05:56.5114690Z Your package was pushed.
2016-08-25T11:05:56.5184487Z ##[debug]rc:0
2016-08-25T11:05:56.5194508Z ##[debug]success:true
```

Comment: It works fine for me. >but the packages available both on the packages tab page on VS Team Services and nuget package manager in visual studio do not update.  You said available, is it a mistake? Do you mean unavailable? What's the result if you publish the package to the feed through command line on your local machine? Make sure the version is changed in nuspec file.

Comment: Sorry no I mean the available packages are past builds from before I started experiencing this problem.

Comment: Interestingly by deleting the feed from the packages tab and adding a new one seems to have fixed the issue. Not sure why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, the issue has been fixed by deleting the feed from the packages tab and adding a new one.